# 'link' feature in pdfpages package does not work

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, bookmarks

I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284632/include-multiple-pdf-documents-and-create-bookmark-to-first-page) answer to merge many pdfs together with automatic bookmarks. In spite of the fact that it worked 1 time (before updating packages with MiKTeX), now I keep getting an error which makes bookmarks link to random pages:

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Topic\0401\040-\040Introduction\040to\040Measurment
>   .pdf.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

I would like to find a solution since this code is easy to automize and it may often be useful since I do not want to pay for any software. (If you know a better way tell me please).

An example of the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pdfminorversion = 6

\begin{document}

    \includepdf[pages=-, link]{Topic 1 - Introduction to Measurment.pdf}

    \bookmark[dest={Topic 1 - Introduction to Measurment.pdf.1}]{1. Introduction to Measurment} 

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: Do you think I should change the names of the actual files then?

Comment: Yes, without the spaces it works.

Comment: Yes it worked, I am such a noob ahahah. Thank you! I lost so much time on this.

Comment: The problem is that `bookmark` properly escapes the space in the file name, while `pdfpages` doesn't. Instead of renaming your file, you could use the `linkname` option of `pdfpages`: `\includepdf[pages=-,link,linkname={Topic1}]{...}` and then `\bookmark[dest={Topic1.1}]{...}`

Comment: I had already tried that before writing the question, it doesn't work though